# How to do enchanting correctly in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm very confused with the process of getting/making enchantments for armor and weapons. Will someone please give me the full guide to enchanting or give me a descriptive enchanting link?

Comment: It feels like this question is too broad and would more likely be better suited to another kind of site. This is not a place for general extended guides like a wiki. I also think this is probably well documented in many places such as some appropriate wikis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting#Skill_Usage is the link you want.

The actual mechanics of how to enchant and disenchant, I will copy from the link.  UESP's page on Enchanting says:

> To use the enchanting skill, you will first need access to an arcane enchanter. These stations enable you to both disenchant weapons that you already have in order to learn their enchantments and create newly enchanted weapons using the enchantments you currently know.
>
> To disenchant an item, all that is necessary is the item that you wish to learn the enchantment of. Open up the enchanting interface at an arcane enchanter, select the option for Disenchant, and select the item you wish to disenchant. Items available to be disenchanted will appear white, while items with enchantments that you already know will appear greyed out. Note that many items, such as artifacts and even most unique items, cannot be disenchanted and their enchantments cannot be learned; they will not even appear on the disenchanting list. A list of all available enchanting effects as well as which item types can be enchanted with which effects can be found here. Keep in mind that when you disenchant an item, it will be destroyed and you will only learn the type of enchantment that it contained; the magnitude is irrelevant for purposes of disenchanting.
>
> Three components are necessary for enchanting an item with a new effect:

```
An item to apply the enchantment(s) to.
A learned enchantment (through disenchanting other items) to apply to the item.
A filled soul gem.
```

> To enchant an item, begin by opening up the enchanting interface at the arcane enchanter. Then choose the Item menu option and select the item that you wish to enchant. Note that the type of item you select, be it a piece of armor or a weapon, will determine what effects can be placed upon it. Next, select the enchantment (or enchantments if you have the Extra Effect perk) that you wish to place on the item. If the item you selected is a weapon, then when you choose an enchantment you will also be able to tune a slider before confirming the enchantment. Moving the slider to the left will increase the number of charges that your item has, but decrease the magnitude of the effect applied. Once you have chosen your enchantment(s), you will then select a soul gem for use. When you pick a soul gem to use, the magnitude of the enchantment(s) you placed on the item will be scaled by the magnitude of the soul gem's soul. If the soul gem you wish to use is greyed out, then it is not strong enough to enchant the item with your selected enchantment with at least one charge at your selected magnitude; reduce the magnitude, or if you deselect the enchantment, then you can reselect the same enchantment and the magnitude slider will start at the minimum magnitude.
>
> When enchanting an item, you can rename the item. Note that while the name you choose appears in all capital letters in the enchanting interface, it will use the capitalization you specify in the inventory and favorites menus.

```
 On PC, type F (by default) to enter a name.
 On Playstation, press Triangle to enter a name.
 On Xbox, press the Y button to enter a name.
```

> Once you have confirmed all of the features of the item you wish to create, select the Enchant option from the menu to complete the process.

*The above quote was slightly edited for format.*

Now that you know how to do it, here's your guide to doing it well.  Basically, there are three main parts to "doing Enchanting right".  The first two can be done in either order, and usually overlap.  These are:

- Obtaining the enchantments you want and need, and
- Leveling up your Enchanting skill, preferably to max.

Getting enchantments is fairly simple, although a few of them are hard to find.  Most objects with special effects in the game can be disenchanted to get their effects as enchantments.  Once you've disenchanted a single item with a given effect, you can create as many items with that enchantment as you want.  So adding to your enchantment library is as easy as remembering which ones you're looking for and buying them / looting them when you see them.  Since enchanted items virtually always sell better than unenchanted ones, you're probably already looting them first in dungeons anyway.

Leveling up your enchanting skill isn't too tough, either.  Disenchanting items gives enchanting skill experience, so you're already doing that.  Enchanting items also adds skill exp, of course, so enchanting lots of items is a key step.  Bigger enchantments (from bigger soul gems) give more exp, so most people recommend getting [Azura's Star](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Azura%27s_Star) or [The Black Star](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Black_Star_%28item%29) and using to help.  Recharging items contributes a tiny amount of exp, but you can do it while in dungeons, and if you do so using one of the Stars you won't even be wasting soul gems, so if you want to do that too, go for it.

My personal strategy for leveling up Enchanting will also take care of your cash supply.  I buy, loot, or steal every soul gem I can find.  All of them.  As soon as I can, I get either the Soul Trap spell or preferably the Soul Trap enchantment.  Soul Trap everything you fight (except people, unless you have the Black Star).  By carrying a surplus of all five gem types, you can be sure you're not "wasting" a big gem on a small soul.  If you put Soul Trap on a weapon, it will automatically Trap the souls of the creatures you kill with it;  it's been a while since I tested, but I'm pretty sure you can also enchant your follower's weapon the same way.  Recharging the Soul Trap weapon is just more free Enchanting exp.  When you return to town, don't sell anything until you've visited the Enchanting Station and enchanted every scrap of loot you're about to sell.  A little experimenting will discover which enchantments give the most money for which slots, if money interests you.  (Paralyze and Turn Undead work well for weapons.)  If you're also training Smithing at the same time, mass producing Iron Daggers and enchanting them works great.  During this phase, I usually stockpile my Grand Soul Gems with Grand Souls trapped in them to save for step 3.  Use the money from selling your amazing enchanted items to buy more soul gems (and anything else you want, as it's usually substantial).

Then, finally, on to step 3:

- Creating your gear.

Some people use temporary boosts and convoluted loops to get a super-high Enchanting score, while others just go with a full set of Fortify Enchanting gear and their single best Fortify Enchanting potion.  Whatever works for you is fine.  Either way, step 3 culminates in you getting together the gear you want to wear, the handful of Grand Soul Gems with Grand Souls it'll take to make them, and whatever boosts from other enchanted gear or potions you want to make your Enchanting even better.  Note that if your Enchanting is level 100 and you take the final perk, you can enchant each item with two enchantments, making you twice as effective.  Put on your Enchanting gear (if you made any) and drink your Enchanting potion (if you brewed one) and do the deed.  When you're done, you'll have the best gear in the game...  until you decide to make more.